# How to format something in an array in a drupal module and bypass checkmarkup for that?

Tags: drupal

```
$events = array();

foreach ($items->items as $item) {
  $node = node_load(array('nid' => $item->nid));

  $body_value  = !empty($body_field) && !empty($item->$body_field)  ? $item->$body_field :  $node->images['thumbnail'];

  $event = array('description' => check_markup($body_value, $body_format, FALSE),);
```

this is a piece of code in a drupal module
where the final output in seen in browser as `files/images/image-x.jpg`

HOWEVER I will like to display this as an actual image by converting it to `<image src=http://mysite.com/$node->images['thumbnail']>` so that browser output is 
`<image src=http://mysite.com/files/images/image-x.jpg>`

How do I now write `$node->images['thumbnail']` and bypass the `check_markup($body_value` as `check_markup($body_value` strips html?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to run `check_markup` on the `<img>` that you create so you could just do it beforehand:

```
if (!empty($body_field) && !empty($item->$body_field)) {
  $body_value = check_markup($item->$body_field, $body_format, FALSE)
}
else {
  $body_value = '<img src="' . $node->images['thumbnail'] . '" alt="alt text" />';
}

$event = array('description' => $body_value);
```